# Como seria um evento similar ao que ocorre no input range?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Estou criando uma barra de progresso personalizada para vídeos, porém estou com uma certa dificuldade em detectar quando o user tentar arrastar a palheta pela barra de vídeo, quero simular algo parecido com o que acontece num `input type rage`

```html
<input type="range" value="50" max="100" min="0" />
```

No mesmo, quando o usuário clica no input e arrasta o cursor sobre o mesmo a paleta segue a posição do cursor na barra, como seria simular isso com um elemento normal?

Aqui está a estrutura básica da minha barra:

```css
.progress_input{
    width:100%;
    height:5px;
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    transition: 0.3s ease-in;
    cursor:pointer;
background:#000;
}

.progress-thumb{
    z-index:5;
    background: #41b8c6;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width:12px;
    height:12px;
    transition: 0.1s ease-in;
    position:absolute;
    left:0%;
    top:-3.50px;
}
```

```html
<div class="progress_input"> 
  <div class="progress-thumb"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Aconselho que você dê uma olhada nesse link: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_event.asp. Veja as seções Mouse Events e Drag Events